# arm64/x86_64 universal binary created with lipo is missing deployment target

Tags: x86, arm64, otool, deployment-target, lipo

### Context

I'm converting several libraries/frameworks that my Mac app uses to be Universal Binaries for the new Apple Silicon Macs.

### Problem

I have two versions of a binary framework: one compiled for `x86_64` and one compiled for `arm64`. I always check the frameworks with `otool` to make sure the minimum deployment target is set correctly. To do that, I use this command:

```
otool -lv myIntelX86Library.a
```

In the output, I see exactly what I expect:

```
Load command 1
cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
cmdsize 16
version 10.12
sdk 11.0
```

Running the same command on the `arm64` binary produces a minimum version of `11.0`, but that's also expected because no earlier version of macOS supports `arm64`.

#### However:

Once I combine these two libraries into a fat binary using:

```
lipo -create <pathToIntel.a> <pathToArm.a> -output <pathToUniversal.a>
```

When I run `otool -lv` on the Universal Binary, I can no longer find the `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` command anywhere in the output. It does not appear.

How can I verify that the `x86_64` part of a fat binary has the correct deployment target set? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as usual, it's RTFM. When run on a Universal binary, `otool`'s default is to print information for only the host architecture. To print the load commands for the `x86_64` architecture when running on an `arm64` machine:

```
otool -l -arch x86_64 <pathToUniversalLibrary.a>
```

Alternately, to print information for all platforms at once:

```
otool -l arch all <pathToUniversaLibrary.a>
```